# The flabbergasting tale of "FitNesse and the Peekaboo jar"

Tags: java, maven, jar, jenkins, fitnesse

I have :

- A FitNesse server all set.
- A project with fixtures all (more or less) nicely coded.

  - This fixture project is a maven one
  - That depends on the, also mavenised, project that I test
  - It's hosted on a git repository
  - And regularly built by a gentle Jenkins.

All in all, everything should work all fine.

But sometimes, as Jenkins, rebuilds and repacks my fixture's jar, this jar is not recognised anymore by Fitnesse.

This jar's location has been set in a `pom` file given to FitNesse by :

```
!pomFile /var/lib/myfitnesse/configFiles/pom.xml
```

*(which file has not been changed in months.)*

When I go look at my `AcceptanceTests.ClasspathPage` I see my jar file *(when it deign appear)* at the path :

```
/var/lib/myfitnesse/.m2/repository/local/company-name/fixtures/test-fixtures/1.1-SNAPSHOT/test-fixtures-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But when it deign not appear, first thing I do is take my favourite command line interface, go check if my jar file is **actually** missing, and quite amazed am I when I discover it **IS** there. Peacefully waiting to be used.

So I berzerkedly spam my **[CTRL]**+**[F5]** skills desperately hoping that FitNesse will wake up and see that god-forsaken jar. Alas it never does until I decide to rebuild my fixtures through Jenkins.

So in an attempt to check if my jar file is somehow corrupted, I decided to add :

```
!path /var/lib/myfitnesse/.m2/repository/local/company-name/fixtures/test-fixtures/1.1-SNAPSHOT/test-fixtures-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

in my `AcceptanceTests.ClasspathPage`. But this call worked. The "pom inclusion" includes all jars but the one I just built and the "path inclusion" works just perfectly fine.

So if I want to summarize, I get it to work but I would not be able to respect myself if I did let it slide as a case of voodoo behaviour. So I **MUST** ask the question and find the answer :

What am I missing there (because I am frankly certain I am) ?
What am I doing wrong ? What reasonable and logical explanation is there to that (because there IS one, **there has to be**).

---

### Edit to answer to Arnaud Denoyelle

Here is my fixture porject's pom (at least what i can disclose)

```xml
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>test-fixtures-releases</id>
      <name>test-fixtures releases</name>
      <url>file:///${user.home}/.m2/repository/releases</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
      <id>test-fixtures-snapshots</id>
      <name>test-fixtures Snapshots</name>
      <url>file:///${user.home}/.m2/repository/snapshots</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

And he is what you may find related to my fixtures in the /var/lib/myfitnesse/configFiles/pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-fixtures</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: +1 for "berzerkedly". Are you sure that your pom targets the good version of your library? Did you use a release version instead of snapshot?

Comment: `<url>file:///${user.home}/.m2/repository/snapshots</url>` is risky. you might not have the same version in local and on Jenkins.

Comment: `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` is fine.

Comment: Should I mention, this project is not mine but the one I work on at office. The version number has been set by another fellow dev and I am not entitled to change it.
Regarding the `<url>file:///${user.home}/.m2/repository/snapshots</url>` on the machine running FitNesse `/var/lib/myfitnesse/.m2` is a symbolic link pointing at the .m2 of the "user" executing the jenkins tasks.
So the path does not seem to be the issue at stake.